# How to capture multiple instances of the same group in Rust regex?

Tags: regex, rust

Here is my text:

```
hello: 3 32 2 8
```

I want to capture it with the following regex:

```
^([a-z]+):( [0-9]+)+$
```

I'm doing this:

```
let txt = "hello: 3 32 2 8";
let re = Regex::new("^([a-z]+):( [0-9]+)+$")?;
let caps = re.captures(txt);
println!("{caps:?}");
```

I'm getting only the last number `8` in the second capture group:

```
Some(Captures({0: Some("hello: 3 32 2 8"), 1: Some("hello"), 2: Some(" 8")}))
```

I suspect that it is an expected behavior of `captures`, but what is the workaround?

Comment: What do you want the result to be? All the numbers separated by spaces (as in the input) in the second group?

Comment: Ideally, I want each number to stay in its own group (this is how it works in Java and Ruby, for example, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: I think you might have to split this into two regexs, one for the text and one for the number. When capturing the numbers you can use `captures_iter` to iterate over all (full) capture groups.

Comment: @Netråm this is what I figured too, thanks. Feel free to submit an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Netråm the doc mentions it returns all the `non-overlapping captures groups`? Could you explain the concept in this context?

Comment: @yegor256 I can't test any Rust code right now, and my answer would not be much more than my comment. If you can code, and test, this before I can you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: @AshishSingh `captures_iter` can be thought of as running `captures` multiple times, cutting out the part in capture group 0 after each iteration. Meaning the groups in each capture will not be different from what would have ben captured by `captures`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply capture the whole sequence of integers.
Since we know this substring has the expected shape, we can split and parse it with confidence (except if one integer has too many digits).

Note that I added some tolerance around white-spaces.

```rust
use regex::Regex;

fn detect(txt: &str) -> Result<(&str, Vec<u32>), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let re = Regex::new(r"^\s*([a-z]+)\s*:((\s*[0-9]+)+)\s*$")?;
    let caps = re.captures(txt).ok_or("no match")?;
    // starting from here, we know that all the expected substrings exist
    // thus we can unwrap() the options/errors
    let name = caps.get(1).unwrap().as_str();
    let values = caps
        .get(2)
        .unwrap()
        .as_str()
        .split_ascii_whitespace()
        .filter_map(|s| s.parse().ok()) // FIXME: overflow ignored
        .collect();
    Ok((name, values))
}

fn main() {
    for txt in [
        "hello: 3 32 2 8",
        "hello :\t3 32   2 8",
        "\thello :\t3 32   2 8  ",
        "hello:",
        "hello:9999999999 3",
    ] {
        println!("{:?} ~~> {:?}", txt, detect(txt));
    }
}
/*
"hello: 3 32 2 8" ~~> Ok(("hello", [3, 32, 2, 8]))
"hello :\t3 32   2 8" ~~> Ok(("hello", [3, 32, 2, 8]))
"\thello :\t3 32   2 8  " ~~> Ok(("hello", [3, 32, 2, 8]))
"hello:" ~~> Err("no match")
"hello:9999999999 3" ~~> Ok(("hello", [3]))
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be possible. Not just with Rust's Regex crate, but with most regex engines.

One way to parse things like this is with nom:

```
use nom::character::complete::i32 as cc_i32;
use nom::combinator::all_consuming;
use nom::error::Error;
use nom::Finish;
use nom::{bytes::complete::tag, multi::separated_list1, sequence::tuple};

fn main() {
    let txt = "hello: 3 32 2 8";
    let numbers = parse(txt).unwrap();
    dbg!(numbers);
}

fn parse(input: &str) -> Result<Vec<i32>, Error<&str>> {
    let mut parser = all_consuming(tuple((tag("hello: "), separated_list1(tag(" "), cc_i32))));
    let (_remainder, (_hello, numbers)) = parser(input).finish()?;
    Ok(numbers)
}
```